# Modifying XML element in java

Tags: java, xml

I am looking for an element "storage.hostname" and modifying that element.

Here is my piece of code,

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class testXML {

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws TransformerException {


        String filepath = "C:\\qautilsServer\\target\\";

        String hostname = "psvrhc9";
        update(filepath,hostname);  
}
    public static void update(String destDirectory, String hostname) throws TransformerException{
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        File rexsterFile = new File(destDirectory + "\\titan-rexster-server-2.5.0\\config\\rexster.xml");
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = null;
        try
        {
            docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        }
        catch (ParserConfigurationException e1)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        Document doc = null;
        try
        {
            doc = docBuilder.parse(rexsterFile);
        }
        catch (SAXException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Node nodes1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("storage.hostname").item(0);
        nodes1.setTextContent(hostname);

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(destDirectory + "\\config.xml");
        transformer.transform(source, result);
    }
}
```

I get the same error when i do the following

```
nodes1.getTextContent();
```

My XML looks like this:

```
<graph>
        <graph-name>graph</graph-name>
        <graph-type>com.thinkaurelius.titan.tinkerpop.rexster.TitanGraphConfiguration</graph-type>
        <graph-read-only>true</graph-read-only>
        <properties>

        <storage.backend>hbase</storage.backend>
        <ids.num-partitions>1</ids.num-partitions>
        <storage.hbase.region-count>8</storage.hbase.region-count>
        <cluster.max-partitions>32</cluster.max-partitions>
        <storage.hostname>psvrhc1</storage.hostname>
        <storage.hbase.table>ldmns:titan_db</storage.hbase.table>
        <storage.hbase.skip-schema-check>false</storage.hbase.skip-schema-check>
        <query.force-index>false</query.force-index>
    </properties>
    <extensions>
        <allows>
            <allow>tp:gremlin</allow>
        </allows>
    </extensions>
</graph>
```

I am getting following issue and i have no clue why is this error coming:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredAttrImpl.setTextContent(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

Note: I am running in jre7 and not jre8. The code seems to be working fine with jre8. Since, my project only supports jre7, i can't upgrade to jre8.

I even tried nodes1.setNodeValue(hostname);
but it didnt work.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: post full stacktrace and more code

Comment: Hey Shahzeb, this is the only error i am getting on line nodes1.setTextContent("Kevin");

Comment: Could you please post whole code with proper imports ,java version and stacktrace?

Comment: I would highly appreciate if you could quickly solve this. Thanks. I edited the question with complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice you are having an [AbstractMethodError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html).
Reference says:

> Thrown when an application tries to call an abstract method. Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of some class has incompatibly changed since the currently executing method was last compiled.

I fear you might have issues with your Apache Xerces library. Maybe your runtime is using an older version which does not implement [Node#setTextContent(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#setTextContent(java.lang.String)) (since DOM level 3).

---

Previously I modified your code to create a minimal reproducible case. But in fact it worked fine. Also works when i read from filesystem your full XML in my  Eclipse Java EE 4.5 fresh setup. Probably the code is irrelevant, but I keep it on display just in case.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class TestXML {

public static void main(String argv[]) throws TransformerException {

    try {
        String xml = "<graph>" + "<storage.hostname>psvrhc1</storage.hostname>" + "</graph>";
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));

        Node nodes1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("storage.hostname").item(0);
        nodes1.setTextContent("blah");

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><graph><storage.hostname>blah</storage.hostname></graph>
```

Comment: Thanks Javier. Yes it was using older version of xerces. So i tried replacing it with new version and it worked perfectly. Thanks for the response.